# iFrame with an Exact Size

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How can I change the `Size` from the `iFrame`, if I use this HTML code?

```
   <li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"  href="http://holy-network.com/v4d/index.php?action=logout">Iframe</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `width` and `height` Fancybox's API options within your custom script like:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
 width: 640, // or whatever
 height: 320
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks the style elements are defined in your CSS Style Sheet class "fancybox.iframe" so that is where the width and height would be defined.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: If you read it carefully it does give an answer to his question, which is that he will have to set width and height in CSS stylesheet.